# Very strange saves photos to SD card

Tags: java, android, save

I keep a photo with my application to the array Bitmap.Then when I did need, I call the shots feature `saveAll()` as shown in the code below

```
public void saveAll(View view) {

for (Bitmap b : arrBitmap) {
    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
    try {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            return;
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(convertBitmapToByteArray(b));
        fos.close();

        Toast.makeText(context, "Picture saved: " + pictureFile.getName(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

}

private byte[] convertBitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new   ByteArrayOutputStream(bitmap.getWidth() *
        bitmap.getHeight());
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
return stream.toByteArray();
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
File mediaStorageDir = new File("/sdcard/", "JCG Camera");

if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
    if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
        return null;
    }
}

String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
File mediaFile;
mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" +
        timeStamp + ".jpg");

return mediaFile;
}
```

and photo is saved very strange at first may not Save or Save all but the first or the first did not survive, but then when I further tested the code they may appear,but every time Toast shows that all is saved.Please tell me

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unclear. What did you ask?

Comment: i mean that with this code my picture is saving as it want. it can be saved or not. it can saved all picture except first one... what does it depend?